# Angular 9 HttpClient - TypeError: url.indexOf is not a function

Tags: typescript, angular9

Recently I've been converting an Angular 9 project to dynamically receive its configuration during bootstrap from a JSON file, rather than from the environment files.

After I make the changes, I get the "TypeError: url.indexOf is not a function" error when running tests. From the error stack, the issue appears to be happening in Angulars' HttpClient module. I'm unsure as to why this has become an issue, as my config changes don't modify any of the root Angular modules.

Moreover, I'm unsure of how to fix it. I've searched Google and StackOverflow, and the results often indicate that its an issue with outdated jQuery - specifically, some functions that have been deprecated and are no longer available. But I don't think this is my issue? Again, my config changes don't have anything to do with jQuery, nor have I changed anything jQuery related.

Here's the Stacktrace

```
TypeError: url.indexOf is not a function

      at new HttpRequest (../../packages/common/http/src/request.ts:221:26)
      at HttpClient.Object.<anonymous>.HttpClient.request (../../packages/common/http/src/client.ts:482:13)
      at HttpClient.Object.<anonymous>.HttpClient.get (../../packages/common/http/src/client.ts:1109:17)
      at IService.getIs (src/app/core/services/i.service.ts:49:28)
      at DialogEditComponent.initialiseDropdowns (src/app/modules/components/dialog-edit/dialog-edit.component.ts:122:46)
      at DialogEditComponent.ngOnInit (src/app/modules/components/dialog-edit/dialog-edit.component.ts:83:10)
      at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (../packages/core/src/view/provider.ts:217:15)
      at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (../packages/core/src/view/view.ts:440:14)
      at checkAndUpdateNode (../packages/core/src/view/view.ts:400:12)
      at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (../packages/core/src/view/services.ts:433:44)
      at debugCheckDirectivesFn (../packages/core/src/view/services.ts:394:7)
      at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ng:/DynamicTestModule/DialogEditComponent_Host.ngfactory.js:9:5)
      at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (../packages/core/src/view/services.ts:388:19)
      at checkAndUpdateView (../packages/core/src/view/view.ts:370:12)
      at callWithDebugContext (../packages/core/src/view/services.ts:638:23)
      at Object.debugCheckAndUpdateView [as checkAndUpdateView] (../packages/core/src/view/services.ts:349:10)
      at ViewRef_.Object.<anonymous>.ViewRef_.detectChanges (../packages/core/src/view/refs.ts:284:16)
      at ComponentFixture.Object.<anonymous>.ComponentFixture._tick (../../packages/core/testing/src/component_fixture.ts:113:28)
      at ../../packages/core/testing/src/component_fixture.ts:127:14
      at ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>.ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:386:30)
      at ProxyZoneSpec.Object.<anonymous>.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:117:43)
      at ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>.ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:385:36)
      at Object.onInvoke (../packages/core/src/zone/ng_zone.ts:308:29)
      at ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>.ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:385:36)
      at Zone.Object.<anonymous>.Zone.run (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:143:47)
      at NgZone.Object.<anonymous>.NgZone.run (../packages/core/src/zone/ng_zone.ts:180:50)
      at ComponentFixture.Object.<anonymous>.ComponentFixture.detectChanges (../../packages/core/testing/src/component_fixture.ts:126:19)
      at src/app/modules/components/dialog-edit/dialog-edit.component.spec.ts:62:13
      at ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>.ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:386:30)
      at ProxyZoneSpec.Object.<anonymous>.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:117:43)
      at ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>.ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:385:36)
      at Zone.Object.<anonymous>.Zone.run (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:143:47)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/jest-preset-angular/zone-patch/index.js:52:27)
```

And here's the function where the call seems to be made to the HttpClient module.

```
  public getIs(a: number, b: number, c = false) {
    let params = new HttpParams().set('a', a === 0 ? '' : a.toString());
    params = params.append('b', b === 0 ? '' : b.toString());
    return this.httpClient.get<Instance[]>(Config.settings?.url.baseApiUrl + Config.settings?.url.api.instance, {params})
      .pipe(
        map(items => {
          return c ? items.filter(item => item.isActive === true) : items;
        })
      );
  }
```

Any guidance or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The error means that the url is not a string. The error is too generic that a google/stackoverlow search will yield many unrelated results. Please provide a minimal Reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @SherifElmetainy thank you for your comment! I'm not sure that I can provide a reproducible example, as between the different components and testing infrastructure, the code is quite spread throughout the application. I have however added the Stacktrace and function to my post for added clarity.

Comment: Debug this line: src/app/core/services/i.service.ts:49:28. Make sure that the url passed to the HttpClient.get function is actually a string.